# MLFlow search registered model is not working in R

Tags: python, r, mlflow

I would like to query registered models in mlflow using R api: `mlflow::mlflow_search_registered_models(filter="name='model_xyz'")`. But, it is throwing following error:

```
Error : API request to endpoint 'registered-models/search' failed with error code 404. Reponse body: 'ENDPOINT_NOT_FOUND; No API found for 'POST /mlflow/registered-models/search''
```

I believe this is a **GET** request. But, why it is saying No API found for **POST** request ? Any hints will be appreciated.

For your information, I have mlflow version (R): `mlflow_2.11.1` installed in my system.